# Winforms: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

I have a bunch of background events.

All of them call a log:

```
private void log(string text, params object[] values)
{
    if (editLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        editLog.BeginInvoke(
            (MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.log(text, values);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        text = string.Format(text, values) + Environment.NewLine;

        lock (editLog)
        {
            editLog.AppendText(text);
            editLog.SelectionStart = editLog.TextLength;
            editLog.ScrollToCaret();               
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I get this, but other times not:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Object& editOle)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ScrollToCaret()
       at Program1.frmMain.log(String text, Object[] values) in 
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

P.D: Not always stop at this line, randomly will be one of the three times editLog methods/properties are used. Not always a exception is throw. Sometimes look like the thing freeze. But not the main UI, just the flow of messages (ie: log look like is never called again)

The app is a single form, with background process. I can't see what I doing wrong with this...

**UPDATE**:

I do the suggestion of Mangist, this is the code (the timer fire at 100ms). Same result:

```
private Queue<String> logs = new Queue<String>();
private void timerLog_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (logs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
        {
            editLog.AppendText(logs.Dequeue());
            editLog.SelectionStart = editLog.TextLength;
            editLog.ScrollToCaret();
        }             
    }
}

private void log(string text, params object[] values)
{
    text = string.Format(text, values) + Environment.NewLine;

    if (editLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        editLog.BeginInvoke(
            (MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lock (logs)
                {
                    logs.Enqueue(text);
                }
                //this.log(text, values);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        logs.Enqueue(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of locking a control in the UI thread? You are already guaranteed single thread access by the message pump.

Comment: Well, that lock was pure guess in my part...

Comment: Asa general rule: *never* lock a real object (eg. `this`). Always use a `new object()` member just for locking. See [Why the Great Idea isn't So Great](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx#S7)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the logging starts up very quickly (before the form handle is created).  Check for `editLog.IsHandleCreated == true` before calling any methods on the control.  That can help, otherwise use a thread-safe `Queue<string>` (surrounded with a `lock (obj) {}` statement) and put a timer in your form to periodically read this queue for new logs.

Comment: I implement both and still get the same problem.

Comment: Add a check for editLog.IsHandleCreated == true before appending the text.

Comment: Still the same issue. Even the GUI freeze :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally found the problem. Removing this eliminate the issue (and work with normal BeginInvoke, without tricks, locks and that):

```
editLog.SelectionStart = editLog.TextLength;
editLog.ScrollToCaret();
```

I try using http://nlog-project.org/ and my first attemp work completelly ok (with http://nlog-project.org/wiki/RichTextBox_target). When I set  `autoScroll="true"` get the same error again. This was how I find the issue.